# Why generic function allowed to be called but not create variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

TypeScript allows c to be called but not creating variable in d function.
Why ?

```
function c<R extends { x: number; y: string; }>(ar : R ) {
}
c({ x: 1, y: "" });

function d<R extends { x: number; y: string; }>() {
    const r: R = { x: 1, y: "" }; // Error
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20c%3CR%20extends%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%3B%20y%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%3E(ar%20%3A%20R%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ac(%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%20%22%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20d%3CR%20extends%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%3B%20y%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%3E()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20r%3A%20R%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: You don't know if the type you're creating will have the other properties that type R requires.

Comment: R can be anything that has `x: number` and `y: string`. So it can be `{x: 5, y: 'y', z: 'z'}`. `{ x: 1, y: "" }` is missing `z` field, so you can not assign to R.

Comment: @ritaj where do you see `z` key in type definition?

Comment: In `R extends { x: number; y: string; }`.

Comment: @ritaj Oh. Right. Seems that I need exact type which doesn't exist in TypeScript.

Comment: What are you actually trying `r` to be? Do you want to return it? You could do something like this: `function d<R extends { x: number; y: string }>(ar: R): R {
 const r: R = Object.assign(ar, { x: 1, y: '' });

 return r;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea.